# How to force Netbeans 7.0.1 so that, when we click Run opens always the same tab or window?

Tags: firefox, netbeans

Netbeans 7.0.1
Firefox 7.0.1

How to force Netbeans 7.0.1 or, how can I setup the firefox to, when we do Run it doesn't tell our browser to open a new tab nor a new window ?

The point is to check the page we are testing always on the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As paulsm4 said, the behavior is determined by the browser.

At least in firefox, here's the way to allow Netbeans Run to run on the same tab:

Install the following extension on Firefox:

**Tab Mix Plus**

Under "**Links**" select:
*Open links from other applications in:* "**Current Tab**"

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is determined by your browser (e.g. Firefox), not NetBeans

For example:

```
FF > Tools > Options > Tabs >
  Open new window in a new tab instead= N
```

Comment: I've edited my question since, new window isn't better to the intended result, than a new tab. :) thanks.